# Cannot clean when upgrading grails in Maven

Tags: java, maven, grails

I have a Grails application that uses Maven to build. I wanted to use upgraded version of Grails (from 2.1.0 to 2.3.7). So I just changed version in `pom.xml` and ran `mvn clean install`. `clean` doesn't seem to be running as expected.

```
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 7.472s
[INFO] Finished at: Wed Apr 16 17:32:01 CEST 2014
[INFO] Final Memory: 15M/223M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.grails:grails-maven-plugin:2.3.7:clean 
(default-clean) on project search-web-app: Execution default-clean of goal
org.grails:grails-maven-plugin:2.3.7:clean failed: A required class was 
missing while executing org.grails:grails-maven-plugin:2.3.7:clean: 
groovy/lang/GroovyObject
```

So it looks the project won't clean because there is no class `groovy.lang.GroovyObject`.
I tried also version 2.3.6 and 2.3.5, the result is the same. I expect upgrades to plugins included in `pom.xml` will be also needed, but I think the error would to look different then. Is there someting I can do about it? I tried removing `.m2` and `.grails` caches also, but it didn't help.

Comment: What version of Maven are you using?  Maybe the latest Grails requires a particular version of Maven.

Comment: I was using `maven 3.0.5`, but now I checked `maven 3.2.1` (last stable) and the result is the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make it work I had to add dependency to Groovy itself:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
    <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.2</version>
    <type>pom</type>
</dependency>
```

The project now cleans (still does not compile, but I think it's some other issue now).
It was not needed for the previous version of grails plugin.

I also added:

```
grails.project.dependency.resolver = "maven"
```

in `BuildConfig.groovy`.

Answer (score 0):

have u tried ..> refresh dependencies and then issue grails clean on command line ...some time deleting the bogus file under ./m2 and refresh dependencies might save a lot of time...

also : related to grails maven-clean -U command check this one

```
grails maven help

mavenRepo ("http://my.server/repos/my-grails-plugins") {
    updatePolicy 'always'
}
```

Here are the possible values for updatePolicy:

```
never – Never check for new snapshots
always – Always check for new snapshots
daily – Check once a day for new snapshots (the default)
interval:x – Check once every x minutes for new snapshots
```

> @dude back up those cache folder and run `mvn clean` or `grails referesh dependency` ...at `least you can remove plugin folder or plugins inside that folder by name`

Comment: I removed `.m2`, then did `grails refresh-dependencies`, then did `grails clean`. Unfortunatelly, I still get the same error from `mvn clean install` although `grails compile` runs without any errors (it was the same before).